# how hashCode () behaves in java

Tags: java

Today i was trying the below code and was expecting the output different for both the sysout.

```
public class StringDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = new String("Hi");
        String s2 = new String("Hi");       
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
    }

}
```

But i'm getting the same value. Can anybody please explain me how the thing is working?

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: And check google before asking questions here. The official documentation is quite exhaustive in this topic.

Comment: In your IDE, you can `<shift> + <click>` on `toString()` to see the implementation.

Comment: `System.identityHashCode` should get you the non-matchine hash values you desire.

Answer (score 5):

`String` has its own implementation of `hashCode()` (thankfully) which is based on the contents of the `String`. That being said if you have two equal strings (no matter how were they created), you'll end up with the same `hashCode()`.

Here is the [implementation of `String.hashCode()` from JDK 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode()) (simplified):

```
public int hashCode() {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;
    int len = count;

     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         h = 31*h + val[off++];
    }
    return h;
}
```

As you can see it is based solely on contents of the `String`.

Comment: Important terms that should be mentioned: *dynamic dispatch* and *overriding*

Answer (score 1):

The `hashCode()` specification for String is prescribed by the JLS and based entirely onthe characters of the String. It is predictable and consistent for all versions of java and all JVM starts.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29

```
public int hashCode()

    Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as

         s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]


    using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

    Overrides:
        hashCode in class Object

    Returns:
        a hash code value for this object.
```

Answer (score 0):

String has implemented hashCode in a way that for the same string it will return the same hashCode - note that this is different for objects that do not have hashCode implemented - they usually return different values for hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code for String,

The hash code for a String object is computed as

```
 s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)